# How to set value for row in table if two rows matched with inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table in the database. If Numbercalled matched with phone number I want to update the IsCompanyNumber called to Yes if not matched then No and if the value is Null then it should be unknown.I want do same thing for NumberCalledFrom, if it is matched with Phonenumber column in companynumber table it will say Yes, if not matched it will say No and if value is Null it will say unknown.

```
Create Table Test(
NumberCalled varchar(15)
,IsCompanyNumberCalled Varchar(5)
,NumberCalledFrom varchar(15)
,IscompanyCalledFrom varchar(5)
);

Create Table CompanyNumber(
ID int identity
,PhoneNumber varchar(15)
);
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
UPDATE T
    Set IsNumberCalled = ‘Yes’,
        IsCompanyNumberCalled From = ‘Yes’

FROM CompanyNumber as C
Inner Join Test as T
on T.NumberCalled = C.PhoneNumber AND
 T.NumberCalledFrom = C.PhoneNumber;
```

Comment: show sample data and desire result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far despite the fact that you already know what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you need to store NULL values? You could use a bit to represent true / false. If you want to store NULL / unknown you don't need 15 characters.

Comment: @ConsiderMe I have added what I have done but I am having problem if I try to implement case statement.

Comment: @BlueDan Sometime the files get corrupted and it enters the calledFrom as Null and called to it will give you number so in that condition I want to write Unknown or U.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of confused on desired result but from what it seems like you want to do a case statement would work if you want to do a select statement?

```
Create Table test2 as (
Select 
NumberCalled,
CASE
WHEN a.numbercalled = b.phonenumber then 'Yes' 
WHEN b.phonenumber is null then 'Unknown'
ELSE 'No'
END AS IsCompanyNumberCalled,
IsCompanyCalledFrom 
from test a 
left join companynumber b on a.numbercalled = b.phonenumber);
```